# JSP form redirect to the same page and also send a response to the page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using JSP form to submit data to my servlet. And I am sending a zip file from the servlet, which will be downloaded in client's computer. My JSP form has following action:

```
<form action="episode_xml" method="post" onsubmit="return validatefile()" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I tried to use get request dispatcher to redirect response to the same jsp. However, as I am already writing the zip file as response, java servlet is not allowing me to redirect to the same jsp page.

Comment: Can you use javasript ?

Comment: I can use Javascript. validatefile() is a javascript function where I am validating the input data. However, I tried to put the location.reload() in the function which didn't help

Comment: The zip file will be written to the response coming from the servlet?

Comment: You can do it using ajax request. Send form data over ajax, and if request is successful, change `window.location` to file url. Can you use ajax request?

Comment: @Ken Bekov: I will read on Ajax. I have not tried ajax yet